# My attempts counter will not decrease in my while-loop?

Tags: python, for-loop, while-loop, counter, limit

Can anyone please help me with limiting my hangman type game to allow only 10 wrong attempts?

The game will not stop after 10 incorrect guesses. It also always displays "10 guesses left" no matter how many incorrect guesses have been entered. What am I doing wrong? How can I make my counter decrease? I have tried moving the code out of a main function but it also does not help. It seems like I am formatting this counter properly, yet it does not behave the way I intend it to.

I know that there are many questions on this site like this and I have tried many solutions that I can not figure out how to work on my code. Can anyone please tell me where I am going wrong here? Any and all help is extremely appreciated. Thank you in advance!

```
    # store words here, one will be randomly chosen for answer
    word_list = ['karma', 'man', 'hippo', 'angel', 'whatever']
    # generate a random answer from list
    answer = (random.choice(word_list))

    hidden_answer = '_'* len(answer)

    hidden_answer = list(hidden_answer)

    past_guesses = [ ]

    guesses_left = 10

    input_prompt = "Guess a letter. (You have " + str(guesses_left) + " guesses left)"

    #to display instructions
    def display_instructions ():
        instructions_file = open("instructions.txt", 'r')
        instructions = instructions_file.read()
        instructions_file.close()
        print(instructions)    

    def main ():
        display_instructions ()
        while guesses_left <= 0:
            print (hidden_answer)
            guess = input (input_prompt)
            past_guesses.append(guess)
            #check all characters in range of answer length
            for x in range (0, len(answer)):
                if guess == answer[x]:
                    hidden_answer[x] = guess
        
                if guess != answer[x]:
                   guesses_left = guesses_left - 1
            print("Your answer so far is:" , "".join(hidden_answer))
         if guesses_left = 0:
              print( "you lose" )
         if "_" not in hidden_answer:
              print( "you win" )

    main ()
```

Comment: In main function, change "while guesses_left > 0"

Comment: guesses left cannot be smaller than zero

Comment: Or you can write "while guesses_left != 0". which means guesses left not equal to zero

Comment: Your guesses variable is set to 10, while your while loop runs as long as guesses <=0. The condition immediately fails.

Answer (score 0):

Add the following statement at the beginning of your main() function :     **global guesses_left**

Your main() function should look like this:

```
def main ():
    global guesses_left
    display_instructions ()
    while guesses_left > 0:
        print (hidden_answer)
        guess = input (input_prompt)
        past_guesses.append(guess)
        #check all characters in range of answer length

        for x in range (0, len(answer)):
            if guess == answer[x]:
                hidden_answer[x] = guess  
            if guess != answer[x]:
               guesses_left = guesses_left - 1
        print("Your answer so far is:" , "".join(hidden_answer))
    if guesses_left == 0: 
          print( "you lose" )
    if "_" not in hidden_answer:
          print( "you win" )
```

When you initialize "guesses_left = 10" outside all the functions, it creates a **global variable** called "guesses_left". However, when you write "guesses_left = guesses_left - 1" inside the function, python creates another local variable with the same name. Hence, you get an error saying, "Local Variable referenced before assignment" as the local variable "guesses_left" was never initialized.

The solution to this is adding the statement "global guesses_left" in the function which simply translates to "a global variable called "guesses_left" already exists and don't create a new one". This will make sure that only one variable called "guesses_left" exists in your program.

Also, to check if "guesses_left" is equal to 0, you have to do:

```
**if guesses_left == 0:**
```

and not

```
**if guesses_left = 0:**
```

Your while loop changes as following too:

```
while guesses_left > 0:
```

Feel free to ask your doubts in the comments!

Comment: But still game is not running the way it should.

Comment: Can you provide me with your entire code please, I'll have a look.

Answer (score 0):

```
import random

word_list = ['karma', 'man', 'hippo', 'angel', 'whatever']
# generate a random answer from list
answer = list(random.choice(word_list))

hidden_answer = '_' * len(answer)

hidden_answer = list(hidden_answer)

past_guesses = []

guesses_left = 10

# to display instructions
def display_instructions():
    instructions_file = open("instructions.txt", 'r')
    instructions = instructions_file.read()
    instructions_file.close()
    print(instructions)


def main():
    global guesses_left
    display_instructions()
    while guesses_left != 0:
        print(hidden_answer)
        guess = input("Guess a letter. (You have " + str(guesses_left) + " guesses left)")
        past_guesses.append(guess)
        # check all characters in range of answer length
        for x in range(0, len(answer)):
            if guess == answer[x]:
                hidden_answer[x] = guess
        if guess not in answer:
            guesses_left -= 1
        print("Your answer so far is:", "".join(hidden_answer))
        print(guesses_left)
        if hidden_answer == answer:
            print("you win")
            break
    if guesses_left == 0:
        print("you lose")


main()
```

Now this game will runs fine check it. The improvements I made in the code are -- First I convert the answer variable to a list which makes it more accessible. Then I use global guesses left inside the main() because this variable is outside the function. Then while guesses left <= 0 is changed to != 0 because guesses_left cannot be smaller than zero. Then input_prompt details are directly put inside guess input. Then " if guess not in answer" is pulled outside the for loop because inside for loop it is changing the guesses_left variable randomly. Then I use break statement after answer matches hidden answer so that while loop will break after correct answer. Finally I pulled "print("you lose") statement outside while loop.